# Как сформировать урлу с параметрами?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

у меня есть урла

```
women/verhnyaya-odezhda/palto?prices=4&prices=2&sizes=2&sizes=6&sizes=10&colors=2&colors=3&conditions=1&conditions=2&brands=183
```

она формируеться когда я выбераю параметры из фильтра.

на другой странице, я могу достать эти параметры с бекенда. и мне нужно сформировать точно такую же урлу, и перейти на нее.

пытаюсь сделать это с помочью generatePath но ничего не получаеться

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Answer (score 0):

Может я неверно понял вопрос, но полагаю что всё просто:

```
url = 'http://women/verhnyaya-odezhda/palto?prices='+$v("param1")+'&prices='+$v("param2")+'&sizes='+$v("param3")+'&sizes='+$v("param4");
w = open(url,"winLov");
w.focus();
```

`$v("#name")` не обязательно использовать, любой другой способ вывести параметр в строку пойдёт.

Comment: проблема в том, что я не знаю изначально сколько sizes мне прийдет) может быть и 1 и 4

Answer (score 0):

Все гениальное просто

> На самом деле, хороший вопрос требующий знать специфику стандартной библиотеки, метод `set` объекта `URLSearchParams` затирает предидущее значение, а `append` добавляет новое

```
const url = new URL('https://yandex.ru/search');
url.searchParams.append('text', '1');
url.searchParams.append('text', '2');
url.searchParams.append('text', '2');
console.log(url.toString()); // https://yandex.ru/search?text=1&text=2&text=2
```